# Adding ComboBox to a datagridview for a particular row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a requirement to show drop down list to one particular row among several rows.
My dataGridView has 2 columns (Parameter and Value) and I am adding 3 rows dynamically in code. For all 3 rows, paramter texts are fixed and can't be modified by user. For first row, Parameter text is "prm1" and Value text will be chosen from drop down list. other 2 rows, Value text will be text box entered by User. I tried searching but couldn't find the answer. Please help me here.

Comment: I don't think what the title infers is the right way to go about this. You could make the first column a [`DataGridViewComboboxCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcell.aspx) and just set this to read-only for certain rows, rather than trying to have the column's cell type different dependant on row.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to replace specific DataGridView cells at run time - in your situation for example where you want a combobox in one cell you can have a DataGridViewTextBoxColumn and replace the cell in the first row. Something like this:

```
void dataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    books.Add(new Book { bookID = 1, bookName = "Test-Driven Development (Kent Beck)" });
    books.Add(new Book { bookID = 2, bookName = "Refactoring (Martin Fowler)" });
    books.Add(new Book { bookID = 3, bookName = "Code Complete: 2nd Edition (Steve McConnell)" });
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell c = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

    c.DataSource = books;
    c.Value = 1;
    c.ValueMember = "bookID";
    c.DisplayMember = "bookName";

    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] = c;
}
```

You can also do this the other way and replace a particular combobox cell from a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with a DataGridViewTextBoxCell.

---

One thing though - while this will work, better usability might just come from setting some combo boxes to read only.

Comment: It seems that I cannot bind a List<string> as the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell `'s DataSource?

Answer (score 2):

Please consider adding of *ComboBox* column to grid with right-click context menu item **Edit Columns...** of the grid in *Form Designer*. To add column it will require to click on **Add** button of **Edit Columns** dialog and subsequently select *Type* = `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` as shown below:

[image]

**Please note**: You will also need to use either [Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.items.aspx) or [DataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx) property of the column to populate drop-down list of the ComboBox.